# curl not working for https

Tags: php, curl

I am trying to use https href in curl (URL is https://), but always throw error: 
302 Unable to connect to server. Please come back later. Where can be problem?

```
                $ch = curl_init();
                $curlConfig = array(
                    CURLOPT_URL => $URL,
                    CURLOPT_POST => true,
                    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
                    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
                    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => false,
                    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => array(
                        ... data ...
                    )
                );
                curl_setopt_array($ch, $curlConfig);
                $result = curl_exec($ch);
                if (!$result) {
                    $http_code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
                    curl_close($ch); // make sure we closeany current curl sessions 
                    die($http_code . ' Unable to connect to server. Please come back later.');
                }
                echo $result;
                curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: please use     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, false); or true. let me know if it does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error 302 is a redirection error. The additional "Unable to connect to server. Please come back later." is a wrong statement coming from your own code.

To make php-curl follow redirections, add

```
CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
```

to the curlConfig array.

Answer (score 0):

To set curl option like

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);

Answer (score 0):

set curl option as

```
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
```